# R ggmaps only loading a quarter of the map

Tags: r, ggmap, stamen-maps

Using ggmap to make a map of a lake. All the code works but the results only show a quarter of the map.

I'm using:

```
bbox<-c(left=152.4583,bottom=-32.4009, right=152.5347,top=-32.3672)
Smiths_lake<-get_stamenmap(bbox=bbox,zoom=14)
ggmap(Smiths_lake)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any latitude and longitude coordinations? If so, than you can set limits in your command.

Comment: I thought I already set the coordinates in the bbox line?